# MySQL get time of a specific timezone

Tags: mysql, timezone

I need to get the time of a specific timezone using MySQL.

I tried using [`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz), but it takes 3 arguments, is there any other MySQL function which will return time instead of converting time from one timezone to another?

Comment: @Krupa these edits were not even required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these will work:

**Option 1:**

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
SELECT NOW();
```

**Option 2:**

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','America/New_York');
```